# Intel Distribution for Python and Spyder IDE

Tags: python, performance, intel, python-multiprocessing, intel-mkl

I've just installed the new Intel Distribution for Python because I need some performance improvements with my Skull Canyon NUC, but I don't understand how to use all the packages/modules modified by Intel.

I usually use Anaconda Spyder as my main IDE, how can I "tell" to Spyder to not use the Anaconda standard/included packages/modules instead of the new Intel ones?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spyder menu choose Preferences then click console and click to Advanced settings tab. From there choose the Python interpreter, which came with Intel Distribution.